# Как объединить результаты запросов данных в одной таблице?

Tags: postgresql, sql

Есть следующие запросы:

```
(SELECT name AS "Юр. лицо", balance AS law_balance FROM client WHERE type = 'Юр')

(SELECT name AS "Физ. лицо", balance AS physic_balance FROM client WHERE type = 'Физ')
```

Как объединить данные этих запросов, чтобы получить таблицу со следующими колонками:
Юр. лицо | law_balance | Физ. лицо | physic_balance

Comment: @Jeremen1, по какому признаку они должны сопоставляться?

Comment: @Etki, видимо, по принципу экселя. Ну, просто в две колонки плохо смотрится, лучше в четыре... фейспалм.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, видимо, это задание на защиту лабы и никакого практического применения оно не имеет. Может, кому поможет: решил с помощью FULL OUTER JOIN по колонке id. Получилось немного не так, как я хотел но защиту приняли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select "Law", law_balance, "Phys", physic_balance
from
(select row_number() over (order by name) as rn1, name AS "Юр. лицо", balance AS law_balance FROM client WHERE type = 'Юр') l
full join
(select row_number() over (order by name) as rn2, SELECT name AS "Физ. лицо", balance AS physic_balance FROM client WHERE type = 'Физ') p
on rn1=rn2
```